# 405.0 Method not allowed on IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5

A web application with IIS 7.5, ASP.NET, MVC 4 and Windows Identity Foundation is throwing following error:

> Error HTTP 405.0 - Method Not Allowed
>
> Module: StaticFileModule
>
> Notification: ExecuteRequestHandler
>
> Controller: StaticFile

The web application logins first through Windows Identity Foundation on a remote site. This login works fine, but when it redirects you to the local MVC application, the local IIS gives that error.

I tried disabling WebDav and configuring WebDav for all verbs but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completely reinstall IIS. This will delete all bad configurations.

You'll have to reconfigure your app to work with WIF.